# Magento2 upgrade issue in Fetching Tax Value

Tags: magento2

Getting issue on **my cart page** after upgrading to magento 2.3.3, Tax value going wrong

```
Subtotal        $260.00
Tax              $27.44
Australia(10%)   $27.44
```

> Accepted result:    26.00
>
> Actual result:      27.44

Any Help will Appreciate!! 
[image]

Comment: Please check error and log files.

Comment: what i check actually i have speical price 260 and orignal price 274 so what my store doing its add tax on actuall price rather add in special price

Comment: Yes your always default deducted at original price.

Comment: how get on special price

Comment: Have you reindexed after adding special price ?

Comment: all indexing or specific

Comment: Go with all indexing!!

Comment: Is this resolved ?

Comment: no not resolved i run index:reindex

Answer (score 1):

Try this by Changing Orignal Price becuase always tax deducts as per Original Price Default.

You can change this by customization.

Customize this files:

For Configurable products:

Overriding `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`

```
Removed the condition to check is product isn't in a list
```

From:

```
<?php if (!$block->isProductList() && $block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
```

To:

```
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
```

2: Removed 'no-display' class from regular price span

From:

```
<span class="old-price sly-old-price no-display">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]); ?>
    </span>
```

To:

```
<span class="old-price">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
                'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
                'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
                'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
                'include_container' => true,
                'skip_adjustments'  => true
            ]); ?>
        </span>
```

Comment: can you guide in which file make changes

Comment: Yes sure!! I will Help.

Comment: Updated Answer please check, for Configurable products

Comment: actually  i am asking about checkout page on checkout or view cart page tax added from base price i will share image

Comment: i add image in my question